# Mysql cannot make a user

Tags: apache-httpd, kali-linux, mysql

So I am currently running kali linux 4.15.0 and I am trying to run DVWA ( Damn Vulnerable Web Application) 
I tried making the user as:

```
    MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'user'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'p@ssword';
```

But it doesn't change any lines

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I have restarted mysql and apache2 yet I am still stumped as to how to fix it

Comment: It's normal for it to say 0 rows affected.

Comment: To follow what @Devon stated, you can do, after logging in as root and `use mysql;`, then `select * from user;`. You should see the user that you added.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to fix. The command worked fine.

If you run this command in the MySQL shell...

```
select user,host from mysql.user;
```

... it will show that your user has successfully been added.

Note that this user has no (useful) privileges at the beginning, you need to assign them to him via the command `GRANT ...`, then run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` to apply the grant.

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html